# Sql commands fail to execute

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Yesterday my myphpadmin and workbench could not allow me to enter with my credentials. But I fixed the problem by going to `resetpassword.bat`, but now im trying to run commands specifically granting privileges for my old and new databses but root isn't allowing the commands and I get this error:

```
Error Code: 1044. Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'db_dummy'.
```

I can not even revoke the privileges. Any suggestions?

Comment: look in bat file to see what is new password for root (or paste it's code to here as comment, and we can understand well what it done and can answer better)

Comment: USE mysql; 
 
REPLACE INTO user VALUES ('localhost', 'root', '', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y'', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', '', '', '', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, '', ''); 
REPLACE INTO user VALUES ('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y 0, 0, 0, 0, '', ''); 
REPLACE INTO user VALUES ('localhost', 'pma', '', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N''N 0, 0, 0, 0, '', '');

Answer (score 0):

so it made your root password to empty string. login with root without password and make it same as your old password.

Comment: you should check phpmyadmin's configuration file, config.inc.php to see it's user and password. maybe there could be another one.

Comment: its the same dont know whats causing this

Comment: are you using phpmyadmin on the same machine ? users are setting with host, it should be match too.